# The explicitly loading of dll breaks a search of enums with custom attribute

Tags: c#, enums

I have 3 simple projects. 
**All projects are targeted to net4.8 platform. There is no problem for Net Core 3.1).**

1. The first project(*CommonDomain.dll*) contains a custom attribute definition:

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
   public class HumanReadableNameAttribute 
        : Attribute
   {
       public HumanReadableNameAttribute(string humanReadableName)
       {
           HumanReadableName = humanReadableName;
       }

       public HumanReadableNameAttribute()
       { }

       public string HumanReadableName { get; set; }
       public string Comment { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Second project(*Example.dll*) contains enum definition whose the fields use this attribute

   ```
   public enum ChildEnum
   {
      [HumanReadableName]
      One = 0,
      [HumanReadableName]
      Two = 1,
      [HumanReadableName]
      Three = 2,
      [HumanReadableName]
      Four = 3
   }
   ```
3. The last project contains a code that detect enums whose the fields use our attribute. I am using by [IsDefined method](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.attribute.isdefined?view=netcore-3.1#System_Attribute_IsDefined_System_Reflection_MemberInfo_System_Type_System_Boolean_) for detection. The project has references to above projects.

At first, I have written a simple clear code that works fine

```
string[] assemblyPath = { 
               @"Example.dll" 
            };

var assemblies = assemblyPath.Select(g => Assembly.LoadFrom(g));
var types = assemblies.SelectMany(g => g.GetTypes()).Select(g => g).ToArray();
var enums = types.Where(t => t.GetFields().Any(f => f.IsDefined(typeof(HumanReadableNameAttribute), false)));
```

I load the assembly with enums and find all enums whose fields contain our custom attribute. The enums collection is not empty.

Now, I will load additionally the itself assembly that contains the definition of custom attribute.

```
 string[] assemblyPath = { 
           @"CommonDomain.dll" // loading the assembly with attribute definition
           @"Example.dll" 
        };

 var assemblies = assemblyPath.Select(g => Assembly.LoadFrom(g));
 var types = assemblies.SelectMany(g => g.GetTypes()).Select(g => g).ToArray();
 var enums = types.Where(t => t.GetFields().Any(f => f.IsDefined(typeof(HumanReadableNameAttribute), false)));
```

This change breaks a search of enums. The enums collection is empty now. I am very surprised.

Why? How the loading of assembly with custom attribute definition affects on IsDefined method?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the behavior you are seeing.  The `enums` collection has one item as `Example` for `Example.dll` and/or `CommonDomain.dll`.

Comment: I am seeing that in two different solution. The target platform is net48.

Comment: I used .NET Core 3.1 for all assemblies.

Comment: @sanmcp, it seems like this strange behaviour appears for only net4.8. Everything is fine for Net Core 3.1 for me too.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue in .NET framework 4.8 too.  Looks like there may be something else is happening with your environment.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I too. I see it on all net platforms. Once I switch to netcore platform, the problem leaves.